# Take all produts by category

Tags: wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic

I don't know why i can't take the products by category name. I get no product found.
The code look like this

```
 <ul class="glide__slides">
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'category_name' => 'trofee',
        'posts_per_page' => 20,
        'meta_query'     => array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array( // Simple products type
                    'key'           => '_sale_price',
                    'value'         => 0,
                    'compare'       => '>',
                    'type'          => 'numeric'
                ),
                array( // Variable products type
                    'key'           => '_min_variation_sale_price',
                    'value'         => 0,
                    'compare'       => '>',
                    'type'          => 'numeric'
                )
            )
    );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        global $product;
        $id = $product->get_id();
        echo '<li class="glide__slide">';
        echo '<br /><a href="'.get_permalink().'">' . woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail().' <br> '.get_the_title().   '<br>' . '<div class="bf-sale"><span>' . $product->get_regular_price() .' Lei </span>' . '<span>' . $product->get_sale_price()  .'Lei</span></div>' .'</a>';
        echo '<div class="trophies-container__trophy-action">';
        echo sprintf(' <a href="?add-to-cart=%d data-quantity="1" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart" data-product_id="%d" data-product_sku=""  rel="nofollow"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>Adaugă în coș</a>',$id,$id);
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</li>';
        endwhile;
    } else {
        echo __( 'No products found' );
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`category_name` is for category taxonomy, sense products use the `product_cat` you will need to add a `tax_query` into `$args`.
Like this.

```php
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 20,
    'tax_query' => [
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'field'    => 'name',
        'terms'    => 'trofee',
    ],
    'meta_query'     => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array( // Simple products type
            'key'           => '_sale_price',
            'value'         => 0,
            'compare'       => '>',
            'type'          => 'numeric'
        ),
        array( // Variable products type
            'key'           => '_min_variation_sale_price',
            'value'         => 0,
            'compare'       => '>',
            'type'          => 'numeric'
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Hmm its display something,but i get some product from another category 'medalii'

Comment: @DigitalPoint Could it be that those products are connected to multiple categories, that one of them is trofee? if thats the case you will need to exlude all other categories.

Comment: The 3 product are in categories 'medalii' and 'medalii de metal' but they have nothing to do with the category 'trofee'

Comment: The sort not working,it just display some products. For example if i put there 'medalii' display the same products